# How can I use Nokogiri with Ruby to replace values in existing xml?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 with the lastest Nokogiri gem.  I have worked out how to extract values from an xml using xpath and specifying the path(?) to the element.  Here is the XML file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<File xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Houses>
        <Ranch>
            <Roof>Black</Roof>
            <Street>Markham</Street>
            <Number>34</Number>
        </Ranch>
    </Houses>
</File>
```

I use this code to print a value:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open ("C:\\myfile.xml"))  
puts doc.xpath("//Ranch//Street")
```

Which outputs:

```
<Street>Markham</Street>
```

This is all working fine but what I need is to write/replace the value.  I want to use the same kind of path-style lookup to pass in a value to replace the one that is there.  So I want to pass a street name to this path and overwrite the street name that is there.  I've been all over the internet but can only find ways to create a new XML or insert a completely new node in the file.  Is there a way to replace values by line like this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the [`content=` method](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#content=-instance_method):

> Set the Node’s content to a Text node containing `string`. The string gets XML escaped, not interpreted as markup.

Note that [`xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) returns a NodeSet not a single Node, so you need to use `at_xpath` or get the single node some other way:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open ("C:\\myfile.xml"))  
node = doc.xpath("//Ranch//Street")[0] # use [0] to select the first result
node.content = "New value for this node"

puts doc # produces XML document with new value for the node
```

Comment: This is great, thank you, it's exactly what I was looking for.  I am finding that the values aren't saving in the file once the ruby program is done running.  I'm looking into a File.save method but if you know the reason this is happening I'd appreciate the help.  Thank you again.

Comment: @user3195786 you will have to write the new contents out again if you want to update the original file. This changes the in memory structure – the file on disk is unchanged.